# When and why did the Swedish locale(s) change from formatting money sums between these formats?

Tags: php, windows-10, locale, number-formatting, icu

I was one of the few people who bothered to learn how to format numbers and money sums. It used to be, and I thought it was still, like this:

```
123 456 789,00
123.456.789,00
```

The first one is a non-money-related number. The second is a money sum.

However, the PHP NumberFormat class (using ICU data, I believe), as well as Windows 10 (at least in the 1903 version) now use this:

```
123 456 789,00
123 456 789,00
```

That is, both non-monetary numbers and money sums are formatted in the same way, with spaces for thousands separators and commas for decimal marks.

When I looked in the Windows settings just a couple of years ago, it still used periods for thousands separators for money sums for Sweden.

This ***must*** have recently changed and been incorporated into both the ICU data and whatever Microsoft uses for Windows. (I assume that they just use the freely available ICU data as well.)

***The problem***: I'm trying to determine when exactly this was changed, and maybe even ***why***. Although I guess it's nice in theory that things are simplified and standardized, there is definitely something valuable and interesting about regional differences, and there certainly are a ton of them in many languages/locales/combinations.

Comment: I feel the "why" would need to be taken up with someone at php.net - The question is far too broad for this area of Stack.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Far too broad? Isn't this extremely specific? I don't understand your comment at all. Also, it's not just about PHP, as stated... I can't help but feel as if nobody reads my questions before replying here.

Comment: The question is not broad at all - it’s very specific.